# Can't install wxPython: Permission denied

Tags: pip

I'm trying to install wxPython with

```sh
pip3 install wxPython --user
```

but getting an extensive error message that seems to revolve around

```
/tmp/pip-install-tdvhv76e/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/configure: Permission denied
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `configure` program at

```
/tmp/pip-install-tdvhv76e/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/configure
```

can't be executed because `/tmp` is mounted with the `noexec` flag.

You can fix this temporarily with

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

to install the package and revert with

```
sudo mount -o remount,noexec /tmp
```

Comment: Or point `TMPDIR` to a directory on a filesystem mounted without `noexec`.